# Tags in reviews for Suggested Edits are confusing and could be clearer?

Tags: discussion

When reviewing Suggested Edits, the text of the question is shown side by side, but the tags are all shown on the left. With no edits to the tags this can make it appear that the original on the left has tags and the suggested edit on the right has no tags.

Of course once a change to a tag is made it becomes clear that the tags are treated differently to the text but otherwise it could be a little clearer.

---

When there is a change it becomes reasonably clear what is goin on, changed tags are highlighted.
[image]

---

When there aren't any changes to the tags, there is no indication to suggest that there are no changes, in fact, logically it appears that the left side (pre-edit) has the tags and the right side (post-edit) has had them removed.
[image: No changes to tags]

Comment: Note that title edits are also shown only on the left side. Do you think in such cases that the edited question has no title, i.e. it's title has been removed?

Comment: @Al.G. That is a good point, perhaps some people are confused by that too? The tags appear to be affiliated with the username and image just below them, which are shown on both the left and right.

Comment: When looking for edits I'm looking for green/red text, so I don't find the tags being only on the left a problem.